# Python and Django how to crypt with a certificate

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, base64, pkcs#12

this is my question:

I want to crypt data with a certificate... Before I used these commands

> openssl rsautl -encrypt -in inputfile -out inputfile.enc -inkey SanitelCF.cer -certin -pkcs
>
> openssl base64 -base64 -e -in inputfile.enc -out inputfile.enc.b64

and it works! But I want to do this with Python(Django)

Can anybody explain me how to do this?

Thank You!

ps: this is the certificate I used (SanitelCF.cer)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

```
first 
i can get the public key by you cert files
the public key is save t.pub
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDUH5fHSeuULFBgCEb4jm8kDwNg
GAacYFY04pq5/gfQvWFEs+m22b/N2V+XTGG9+vBus7CYb2b6KlWUBqH8+abHPR81
zQLWfQammXxUNSSZnXp2q0UrE3T1l7ia5JLQDENdIRKNQctnxtqMtX/d+Inaa8Tr
3KMbDurakhfFvTLR7wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

next;
run the command: sudo apt-get install python-M2Crypto

the end python code is:

from M2Crypto import RSA,BIO
pub_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
tt=file("t.pub").read()
pub_bio.write(tt)
pub_key = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(pub_bio)
message = 'hello word' 
encrypted = pub_key.public_encrypt(message, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
print encrypted
```

Comment: Sorry, Another question... How do you get the public key?

Comment: It says "No module named M2Crypto"... also after I have do "sudo apt-get install python-M2Crypto". How I can install it?

Comment: first get the public key

Comment: run command:openssl x509 -in SanitelCF.cer -outform PEM -pubkey

Comment: No module named M2Crypto    you can run command yum install python-M2Crypto or sudo apt-get install python-M2Crypto or pip install M2Crypto

Comment: Right now, I have the same message "No module named M2Crypto", when I execute "pip install M2Crypto" it says: "Requirement already satisfied"